# rewrite base URL and add a specific word to it using mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

below is my requirement :
Supposing i have a URL coming from browser

```
http://test.aroa.com/mance
```

I need to add /xyz/abc/xy/ before perfomance and .html after it i.e. using re-write rules of mod_rewrite to change it to below URL once it hits the dispatcher in AEM(or apache web-server)

```
http://test.aroa.com/xyz/abc/xy/mance.html
```

For this i wrote the below re-write rule along with some rewrite conditions(rewrite conditions not here)

```
RewriteRule ^(/.*)$ /xyz/abc/xy$1.html [P,L]
```

It works for the this site but messes up some other functionalities by adding  /xyz/abc/xy to other URLs as well

Can you suggest me some way using which i can restrict the URL rewriting only for the //test.aroa.com/ URL and not affect any other URL

I tried putting the rule inside directory tag of with the doc-root name inside it. but it fails to get applied in that case..

Can anyone suggest something that can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to apply your rule on a specific domain, you can add this condition

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.aroa\.com$ [NC]
```

Also, a small semantic detail: you don't need `L` flag with `P` flag (it's redundant, since `P` includes `L`)

Finally, your code should look like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.aroa\.com$ [NC]
# your other conditions
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ /xyz/abc/xy/$1.html [P]
```

Remark: i think you don't need to use `mod_proxy` (`P` flag) especially because it's slower than a simple internal rewrite. If your (sub-)domains share the same document root then you can avoid using it by replacing `P` flag with `L` flag